# Выставить значение checkbox на основании значения переменной

Tags: php, html, checkbox

Есть несколько переключателей на странице типа:

```
<var>
<input id="switch1" class="switch" name="switch1" type="checkbox" />
<label for="switch1">Ручное управление</label>
</var>
```

И есть переменная, значение которой я получаю с MySQL.
Переменную считать проблем нет, а вот как выставить ряд переключателей, используя оператор условия и атрибут checked ума не приложу.

Пытаюсь писать что-то такое, но это естественно не работает.

```
<var>
<input id="switch1" class="switch" name="switch1" type="checkbox" 
<?php
echo 'Manual_control ='; echo $row["Manual_control"];
if ($row["Manual_control"]==1)?> 
checked/>
<?php ?>
/>
<label for="switch1">Ручной режим управления</label><br><br>
</var>
```

Эта заморочка нужна для того, чтобы при загрузке админ страницы переключатели отображали реальную картину включенных и выключенных портов устройства.

Comment: <input id="switch1" class="switch" <?php echo $checked = ($row["Manual_control"]==1) ? "checked":  ""; ?> name="switch1" type="checkbox" >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте скрытый input с тем же именем, со значением 0

```
input type="hidden" name="switch1" value="0"
input type="checkbox" name="switch1" value="1"
```

И сначала делаете проверку, а потом выводите поля с подставленным значением.
Если у вас происходит обновление страницы передавайте переменную дальше через $_POST или $_GET, или другие глобальные массивы.

```
`    $chk=0;
    $row['Manual_control']=1;
    if ($row["Manual_control"]==1) {$chk = 1;}
    echo '<input id="switch1" class="switch" name="switch1" type="checkbox" value"'. $chk. '">';'
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, обернул все в PHP, вот что получилось:

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за подсказки, получилось стандартно состыковать PHP и HTML:

```
<var>
  <?php if ($row["Manual_control"]==1):?>
  <input id="switch2" class="switch" name="switch2" type="checkbox" checked />
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php if ($row["Manual_control"]==0):?>
  <input id="switch2" class="switch" name="switch2" type="checkbox" />
  <?php endif; ?>
  <label for="switch2">Ручное управление</label><br><br> 
</var>
```

При автоматическом обновлении страницы происходит обращение к последней строке БД MySQL, поэтому переключатели так же меняют свое положение на основании значения переменных MySQL